# mongodb - filter users in one collection if they conditionally exist in another

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following scenario

users collection - has 100 users
partnership collection has - a few entries where `from` field is the current user.

Output all rows EXCEPT where `from` field is the current user.

In my example playground below, the user "mmm" is missing in output because its not in partnership collection yet.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/AeAT-pqs8qm

When I perform a lookup from another colection, it already filters users that exist in both collection hence missing all users which are not yet in partnership collection

```
db.users.aggregate([
  // $geoNear
  {$lookup: {
    from: "partnership",//this filters users who are not in partnership collection yet
    let: {
      user_id: "$_id"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  // $geoNear
  {$lookup: {
      from: "partnership",
      let: {user_id: "$_id"},
      pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$ne: ["rrr", "$users.0"]}}}],
      as: "valid"
    }
  },
  {$match: {
      "valid.0": {$exists: true},
      _id: {$ne: "rrr"},
      location: {$exists: true}
    }
  },
  {$sort: {calculatedDist: 1}},
  {$unset: ["location", "calculatedDist", "valid"]},
  {$group: {_id: 0, users: {$push: "$$ROOT"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JzTWLTOtciz)